# Getting the last clicked button as a variable

Tags: python, button, pygame

This is difficult to explain but basically I have a bunch of buttons and these buttons at the same time have their own class and unique variables. I want to be able to get the last clicked button but I do not know how to do this. Here is some code.

```
        a = len(towers)
        currentTower = towers[a-1]
        currentTower.damage += 150
        currentTower.radius += 100
```

What this does is gets the last placed button but I want to get the last clicked. Towers is a variable which stores these buttons in a list. Sorry if this is not explained very well. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If tower is supposed to store a list of button, shouldn't tower be an array then instead of a variable. Your explanation does not match your code because i can see that you are storing the buttons as an array in your code

Comment: Yes it is an array my bad sorry

Answer (score 0):

To get the last clicked button, you could make a global variable and set it in each of your buttons "clicked" event handlers. The global variable could point to the button itself or to its index in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are talking about mouse buttons or keys from the keyboard, but I will consider mouse buttons in my explanation.

So if I understand you have a `class Tower:` which has some attributes like `radius` and `damage` and some methods. You seem to want couple this class with mouse buttons and do some stuff one a specific tower when a specific mouse button is pressed. Well, I suppose you have a main loop somewhere in your script which is checking for pygame events ? Then I propose something like this rigth in this loop:

```
# Before the loop
running = True
mousebutton_tower = {}
# The loop
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # If you quit the game
        if event.type == pygame.locals.QUIT:
            running = False
        # If a mouse button is pressed
        if event.type == pygame.locals.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button not in mousebutton_tower.keys{}:
                mousebutton_tower[event.button] = Tower()
            tower = mousebutton_tower[event.button]
            # Do stuff about this Tower...
```

In this way, by using a dictionary `mousebutton_tower`, each mouse button is coupled with a specific tower and, in the main loop, you can easily find the current tower by checking the last mouse button pressed. Tell me if you need more details or if i am totally wrong about your question...